# Interrogate tempo.js objects for existence

Tags: javascript, tempo

I'm using tempo.js 2.0 and I noticed after my Ajax requests - the response fails to re-render correctly, someone on this site pointed out, tempo.js renders fine if you don't prepare the container again, I tested and they are correct.  This works:

```
var template = null;

function populate(){
    if (template == null){
        template = Tempo.prepare("myDivId");
    }
    template.render(data);
}
```

Anyone know how I can interrogate some value in the DOM or Tempo so I can remove my global variable? var template = null;

The only thing I can think of is using jQuery and testing if tempo el type expressions exists {{ someValue }}

I tried reading the code and I don't understand javascript enough.

Big thanks!

Comment: I dont think it can be done, the examples use global variables, I think I was looking for a isPrepared method.  I'm also learning I suck at javascript.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a wrapper for tempo.js and it handles all first pass logic, if object doesn't exist, create it, else give me the already created object.